# Saving history for script run Rscript through terminal/console

Tags: r, rscript

for my work, I run scripts on virtual machines on a computer cluster. These jobs are typically large and have a big output. What I'd like to do is to run a script via the terminal. In the end, the script creates a duplicate of itself so that it contains every line that was part of the script (minus the last if necessary). This is quite vital for replicability and debugging in my work-life because I sometimes can't see which parameters or variables a particular job included as I submit the same script repeatedly just with slightly different parameters and the folders can't be version controlled.

Imagine this file `test.R`:

```
a <- rnorm(100)


#test

# Saving history for reproducibility to folder
savehistory(file = 'test2.R')
```

Now, I run this via the console on my virtual node and get the following error:

```
[XX home]$ Rscript test.R 
Error in.External2(C_savehistory, file): no history available to save
Calls: save history
Execution halted
```

Is there any command like `save history` that works inside a script that is just executed?

The desired outcome is a file called `test2.R` is saved that contains this:

```
a <- rnorm(100)


#test

# Saving history for reproducibility to folder
```

Comment: Is there a reason Rscript test.R doesn't work?  The history being stored when running a script will just be the script itself right?

Comment: Yes that would be the plan but it doesn't work at least on my linux virtual machine it doesn't.

Comment: No I'm asking why you need to write the history out to test2.R because all that theoretically would contain would be the contents of test.R.  What is the purpose of creating test2.R when test.R already contains the output you want?

Comment: Becuase I want to create the exact duplicate of script that I used to submit a job and save it with time stamp so I am able to go back to it latter when the job is done and look at it again without any subsequent changes that are introduced for submitting it again with on parameter difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the file instead. Since you're using `Rscript`, the script name is included in `commandArgs()` in the form `--file=test.R`. A simple function like this will return the path of the executing script:

```
get_filename <- function() {
  c_args <- commandArgs()
  r_file <- c_args[grepl("\\.R$", c_args, ignore.case = TRUE)]
  r_file <- gsub("--file=", "", r_file)
  r_file <- normalizePath(r_file)
  return(r_file)
}
```

Then you can copy the file as you see fit. For example, appending ".backup":

```
script_name <- get_filename()
backup_name <- paste0(script_name, ".backup")
file.copy(script_name, backup_name)
```